# Is there any English version of Récoltes et Semailles?

Tags: algebraic-geometry, reference-request, soft-question, math-history

I felt like my question isn't appropriate for MO, so I thought maybe I should post it here. I want to read Alexander Grothendieck's "Récoltes et Semailles", but I don't know any French. I can easily find the French version, but as you see I need the English version. I have read that there have been several attempts to translate it into English. Is the full version in English available somewhere? My search lead to a [website](http://www.fermentmagazine.org/rands/recoltes1.html), though I find it kind of hard to navigate, and I don't know how much of the original materials it includes, and of course it is in a web form. I need it in a .pdf or .djvu or any other readable file format.

Comment: It has been translated to some languages other than English, but I do not know about an English version.

Comment: Wikipedia links to existing translations in different languages: https://fr.wikipedia.org/wiki/R%C3%A9coltes_et_Semailles

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think this is right... maybe somebody can confirm the translation is good and possibly fix it up a little bit.

http://attach3.bdwm.net/attach/0Announce/groups/GROUP_3/Mathematics/D4335A993//M.1104367920.A/RS.pdf

Comment: This is an incomplete translation, unfortunately

Answer (score 6):

Saad Slaoui is working on one (work on progress) but he has made a very good progress so far
https://web.ma.utexas.edu/users/slaoui/notes/recoltes_et_semailles.pdf

Answer (score 5):

There apparently is no complete translation into English.  Roy Lisker's translation, linked to above, is 98 pages and covers the Preface, Introduction and the first 18 sections, "Promenade through a life's work - or the Child and the Mother." but not "The Letter" nor "The Epilogue and Post-Script".

Juan Antonio Navarro González has a link to the 929 page French original and also a [translation of the beginning into Spanish](http://matematicas.unex.es/~navarro/res/). There is a translation into [Russian](http://www.mccme.ru/free-books/grothendieck/RS.html).

Answer (score 2):

Alongside Lisker's and Slaoui's cited before. There are other two

[[Ongoing Translation by Sayantan Roy and Amit Kuber]](https://github.com/SayantanRoy95/R-et-S)

[[Ongoing Translation by Tong Zhou]](https://tongchow.github.io/ReS.html)

But they are also incomplete. Maybe you would like to save the links.